# How to increase the content view of NSScrollView horizontally?

Tags: ios, macos, nsscrollview

I am using NSScrollView of size 440x44 , i am creating check buttons dynamically and want to add them in scroll view horizontally not vertically , i have initially added 10 buttons in the scroll view like this

```
self.scrollView.hasVerticalScroller=NO;
self.scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller=YES;
int counter =0; 
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    NSRect frame;
    frame.size.width = frame.size.height = 50;
    if(i>0)
        frame.origin.x=counter;
    NSButton *myCheckBox2 = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [myCheckBox2 setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
    [myCheckBox2 setTitle:@"Hello"];
    [myCheckBox2 setBezelStyle:2];
    [self.scrollView.documentView addSubview:myCheckBox2];
    //[self.scrollView setDocumentView:myCheckBox2];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:myCheckBox2];
    counter=counter+50;
  //  [self.scrollView setHorizontalLineScroll:1000];
}
```

When i run the code i achieved this
[image]

But the problem is i am unable to scroll it horizontally....... How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

set contentSize of your scrollView. That's why you can't scroll.
for example

```
self.scrollView.contentSize(CGSizeMake(1000,50))
```

Comment: i am using NSScrollView not UIScrollView. there is no such property in NSScrollView